# pandas how to multiply all elements of same column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I know it is a simple answer but i could'nt find anywhere, I need to show the multiplication of all values of a single column in python.
Here's the dataframe:

```
    VALUE
0     2
1     3
2     1
3     3
4     1
```

The output should give me 2*3*1*3*1 = `18`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `prod`

```
df.VALUE.prod()
Out[345]: 18
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer you can use `df.product(axis=0)` as well.